# List all directories whose contents (files) have not been updated or accessed before a certain date?

Tags: shell, osx, disk-cleanup

Would like to easily located folders to archive/trash and an easy way to automate this would be to choose folders I haven't made any use of for years. Since folders themselves can have different modification dates than the files they contain, I'm wondering if there's already a *nix command that does this for me.

Otherwise I suppose I could write a script that first locates directories that haven't been updated or accessed before a certain date, and then recursively loop through their contents to make sure they also haven't been accessed or modified since that date.

But if a tool like this already exists, I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /some/where -type d \( -atime +1234 -o -mtime +1234 \) -print | ...
```

Comment: Note that this answer works, but *only* because, in osx at least, it appears that each time a file is accessed, created, or modified, the access time for each of its parent subdirectories is also updated. Probably just the `atime` filter is needed, I can't think of any situation where a directory would be modified but not accessed.

Answer (score 1):

The access time on a directory is rarely useful. The first time you run `ls` or `find` in the directory, its access time is updated.

You could simply look for files that haven't been accessed in a long time:

```
find . -type f -atime +999 -print
```

If you're only interested in directories where none of the files have been accessed in a long time, you can combine a `find` command to explore directories and a `find` command to explore files within a directory.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    recent=$(find "$0" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -type f -atime +999 -print | head -n 1)
    if [ -z "$recent" ]; then printf %s\\n "$0"; fi
  ' {} +
```

Note that this snippet can print out a directory where none of the regular files have been accessed recently but there are files that have been accessed recently. Skipping these isn't easy with `find` alone, unless you just remove `-maxdepth 1` to traverse directories independently which would trigger a lot of repeat disk activity. Here's an untested bash script that does the directory walk manually, keeping track of which directories only contain files that haven't been accessed recently.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob
explore () {
  local entry keep=
  for entry in "$1/"*; do
    if [ -L "$entry" ]; then
      :
    elif [ -d "$entry" ]; then
      if explore "$entry"; then
        keep=1  # Keep this directory, it contains kept directories
      fi
    elif [ -f "$entry" ]; then
      if [ -z "$(find "$entry" -atime +999 -print)" ]; then
        keep=1  # Keep this directory, it contains a recently-accessed file
      fi
    fi
  done
  if ((!keep)); then
    echo "$1"
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}
explore .
```